# Swift pass commands into a jar file

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pipe

I have a java program running in the background of my swift program. The java program can read user input in a command line. How can I pass "commands", or text line into the jar after it has been launched?

Just like the way the program down below read from the java program, how can I then "reply" to it?

```
    let b = Bundle.main
    let path = b.path(forResource: "myjar", ofType: "jar")!
    NSLog("%@", "jar path : \(path)")

    task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/java"
    task.arguments = ["-jar", path]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    let errorPipe = Pipe()
    task.standardError = errorPipe
    task.launch()
    let outHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    outHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
    var progressObserver : NSObjectProtocol!
    progressObserver = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        forName: NSNotification.Name.NSFileHandleDataAvailable,
        object: outHandle, queue: nil){

            notification -> Void in
            let data = outHandle.availableData

            if data.count > 0 {
                if let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                    NSLog("%@", str)

                }
                outHandle.waitForDataInBackgroundAndNotify()
            } else {                 NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(progressObserver)
            }
    }
```

I then tried the following without luck:

```
pipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("text to send to java program".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're pretty close. If you just added the code `pipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("text to send to java program"...` that's not going to work because that pipe is the one you assigned to `standardOutput`.

You need to create yet another `Pipe` object, assign it to `standardInput`, and write to that:

```
   ...
>> let inputPipe = Pipe()
>> task.standardInput = inputPipe
   task.launch()
>> inputPipe.fileHandleForWriting.write("text to send to java program".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
   ...
```